How do I filter requests with root path in Springboot?
The value of servlet.context-path is set to /api in my application.yml, how could I filter the request with root path, i.e., https://www.example.com/?
I tried to register a filter where the urlPatterns is set to / and the order is set to Integer.MIN_VALUE, but it doesn't work, the request against https://www.example.com/ still returns HTTP code 404.

You cannot as the application will only listen to /api and not /. If you would set spring.mvc.servlet.path to /api it would work with a filter on /.
